# has_many through with different primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model-associations

```
 class Foo
  set_primary_key :foo_user_id
 end

 class Bar
  set_primary_key :bar_account_id
 end

 class Baz
 end
```

`Foo` has many `Bar` through `Baz`. How do I write relationship with different primary keys involved?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the primary id on the association by adding `:primary_key => "my_custom_id"`. Check the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to).

```
belongs_to :Foo, :primary_key => "foo_user_id"
```

The rest depends on whether Foo `has_many` or `has_one` Baz.